# slip string in to 2048 bytes chunk

Tags: php

The idea is to take a string and slip it up in to 2048 bytes.

So if i have a 5000 byte string. data.php returns how many chucks being 1 or more. `data.php?chunk=1` returns the first 2048 bytes, `chunk=2` returns the next 2048 bytes and `chunk=3` returns the remaining 904  byes.

I'm not really sure how you would split it up by bytes.

Or is 1 character 1 byte?

I'm working with lsl which only allows 2048 bytes per request, that's why i have to break it into chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is based on standard ASCII characters you can use simply use

```
$chunks = str_split($string , 2048);
```

As each character uses 1 byte , you essentially have 2048 characters covering 2048 bytes.

If you don't want to do that you can also do it like this:

```
$chunk_needed = (int) $_GET['chunk'];
$start_at = ($chunk_needed * 2048 ) - 2048 ;
echo substr($string , $start_at , 2048);
```

Edit:

My apologies, I misread 2048 bytes as 2048 bits and ended up calculating 256 characters. It was incorrect, as each character takes one byte, with 2048 bytes you have 2048 characters. I have fixed the codes above.